# Creating list object in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of objects (this is for a game) and I want to make the list itself an object.

The first object is the card:

```
class card (object):
    def __init__ (self,suit,value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value


    def cardpointvalue(self):
    #not relevant, basically says if card is this return this value for it
    # there is also a __str__ function and a ___repr___ function, don't think
    # they are important
```

So that's my card object, I also have a hand object which is where I'm having trouble.

```
class hand (object):
    def __init__ (self,list_cards):
         self.list_cards = list_cards

    def hand_value (self):
        for i in list:
           handpointvalue += (i.cardpointvalue())
        return handpointvalue
```

In my main(), which is where I'm having trouble.

I have lists where I make each card in the deck into a card object.  I then pass them into the person's hand called list1 and list2 (for each player, for the sake of simplicity I'll deal with list1 only).

Once I've passed each player's cards into their list.  I try to make the list into the hand object then run the `handpointvalue` function on them.

So

```
for i in range(10):
    one_card = card_deck.pop(0) #each card is an object at this point
   list1.append(one_card)

print (list1) #just testing, get a list of each card object
```

Here is where I have trouble. I've tried multiple things, the latest one being:

```
hand(list1)
print (list1.handpointvalue())
```

Why is this not working?  How do I make this object list into a object itself?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, NEVER use built-in keywords as variables' names (e.g. `list`). 
Second, the `hand.hand_value` has an udefined variable (`handpointvalue`) and should just not work. Third, you're not even calling the `hand.hand_value()`:

```
print (list1.handpointvalue())
```

Comment: Right, I know that list should never be used, it was actually just for the sake of this.  So I should make handpointvalue= 0 before I start iterating through the list (which should be called hand)?

Comment: But, that's not really the problem I'm having.  What's happening is I'm getting a typeerror that the object is not iterable.

Comment: The "Object not Iterable" error simply means that you are trying to iterate on an object which does not implement the `__iter__()` method. For example `for x in 10` will raise that error as integers do no implement it. On the other hand `for x in range(10)` works fine, because lists are iterable (implement `__iter__()`). See http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

Comment: @user1887945 the cards are stored in `self.list_cards` but you iterate over `list` (which is the class object of built-in lists) - this gives a type error as classes are in general not iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted a traceback or code that has any reason to work, I'm going to bet that your problem is 3 fold:  1) there's no method called handpointvalue that you've provided us with 2) you're not using self to get at object attributes, and 3) you don't seem to understand how constructors work.

Given the description, this is what I think you're trying to do:

```
cards = [card_deck.pop(0) for i in range(10)]

class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.cards = cards
    def handpointvalue(self):
        return sum([c.cardpointvalue() for c in self.cards])

hand = Hand(cards)
v = hand.handpointvalue() 
# v will now be some number, assuming you've implemented cardpointvalue correctly
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class hand (object):
    def __init__ (self,list_cards):
       self.list_cards = list_cards
       self.handpointvalue = ""

    def hand_value (self):
        for i in list:
            self.handpointvalue += (i.cardpointvalue())
        return self.handpointvalue
```

The problem is you should init handpointvalue in class hand or other ways

Comment: The point value should be a local of the function, not a member variable (calling your function twice, the second result would be two times the first one). Also, it is probably an integer value and not a string... And you failed to see OPs actual problem, which is that he didn't call the right function.